# Elastic search nested objects are not filtered by term

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, elastic-stack

I've the following data on `movies` index:

```
[
  {
    "title": "The Matrix",
    "cast": [
      {
          "title": "Keanu Reeves",
          "score": 76
      },
      {
          "firstName": "Laurence Fishburne",
          "score": 76
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "Wolf of wall street",
    "cast": [
      {
          "title": "Leonardo DiCaprio",
          "score": 76
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Note: I dont have a nested mapping yet because I'll only ever search on a single attribute on cast objects.

when I run the following query with `match`, it returns data:

```
GET /movies/_search
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
              "match": {
                 "cast.title": "Keanu Reeves"
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

But when I try using `term` it doesn't return any data:

```
GET /movies/_search
{
    "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
           {
              "term": {
                 "cast.title": "Keanu Reeves"
              }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `cast.title` field type is **text** and it's analyzed like the following.

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": ["Keanu Reeves"]
}
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "keanu",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "reeves",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 12,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

**It's NOT recommended to use `term` query for text fields:**

> Avoid using the term query for text fields.
>
> By default, Elasticsearch changes the values of text fields as part of
> analysis. This can make finding exact matches for text field values
> difficult.
>
> To search text field values, use the match query instead.
> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

If you want to use a term query you can use `keyword` field type.

```
GET /movies/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "cast.title.keyword": "Keanu Reeves"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```